# Mostrar usuarios hostpot mikrotik

Tags: c#

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en c# para que me ayude ala creacion de usuarios hostpot en mikrotik pero no se como llenar un datagrid con la informacion del que esta en el router me podrian ayudar?

Comment: deberias explicarte un poco mas completo, que es eso del hostpot en mikrotik ? digo es un sitio web que expone alguna webapi que puedes invocar, como obtienes la informacion para llenar el grid, defiens alguna clase y lista? que tipo de aplicacion se trata es winform, web, etc

Comment: tienes la libreria de mikrotik?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la API, tomando el programa en Python que tengo en mis notas y adecuándolo a C#, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
MK mikrotik = new MK("x.x.x.197");
 if (!mikrotik.Login("admin", "123"))
 {
 MessageBox.Show("no connect");
 mikrotik.Close();
 return;
 }
 MessageBox.Show("connect");

 mikrotik.Send("/ip/hotspot/user/add", false);
 mikrotik.Send("=name=999", false);
 mikrotik.Send("=password=999", false);
 mikrotik.Send("=profile=profile1");

 //MessageBox.Show("create user");
 mikrotik.Close();
```

Pero usted debería proporcionar mas datos del error que obtiene.

Comment: No vengo enpesando a programar pero esa parte de mostrar la informacion no se cono hacerla

Comment: en el codigo que publicas, que seria MK ? pareciera ser una clase, pero de donde sale?

Comment: Estoy usando la api de mikrotik para c# pero no estoy seguro de como se usa

Comment: Es parte del paquete c# propuesta por Microtik para su API

Comment: Si pero he investigodo esa parte y hay poca informacion para c# y no se que hacer

Comment: [API C#](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_in_C_Sharp)

Comment: Si pero la parte de mostrar usuarios hostpot no esta y esa es la que ocupo

Comment: La API es cllara. 
Me estas pidiendo que programe por tì.

Yo creo que ya te dado toda la informaciòn que existe.

Dicha API es de un producto propietario. Puede solicitar soporte en lo referente a si existe programas ya confecionados para tu lenguage.

La unica documentación disponible de la API, en lìnea es : [](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API)